# Text classification for unlabeled data

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, semisupervised-learning

I want to classify data into two classes based on parameters given. My data is publications from two different sources and I want to classify it into "match" or "non-match"; when comparing the dataset1 with dataset2. The datasets are unlabeled text data which contain five attributes (id, title, authors, venue, year) so if i apply unsupervised algorithms, it will not produce my target classes. On the other hand, supervised algorithms need to labelled data which is unavailable and time consumed.

- What is the best and easiest method to do that in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best, easiest and AFAIK the optimal method is as follows:

1. Use `clustering` algorithms like `K-Means`, to cluster your data points into 2 clusters.
2. Now, `manually examine a few samples` of one of the cluster and label it accordingly.

Assume you randomly picked 10 data points from the first cluster and they fall in the **match** class. Now all you need to do is label all the data points in this cluster as `match` and label all the data points in the other cluster as `non-match`.

This would give you the required classification.

Comment: will I use this method even though I have the `ground truth` data ?

Comment: If you have the ground truth data then I don't see why you can't run a classifier. So, no you won't use this method. Instead, you would want to use the classification algorithms.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I'm a new user in ML so does there any resources or topics that I can learn from about applying `ground truth` data to run a classifier.

Comment: Consider upvoting and accepting the answer...  And this might give you an overview on classification - https://machinelearningmastery.com/types-of-classification-in-machine-learning/